# Dataproc client : googleapiclient : method to get list of all jobs(runnng, stopped .. etc) in a cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-client, google-cloud-dataproc

We are using Google Cloud Dataproc to run sparkJobs.
We have a requirement to get a list of all jobs and its states corresponding to a cluster.

I can get the status of a job, if I know the job_id, as below

```
res = dpclient.dataproc.projects().regions().jobs().get(
           projectId=project, 
           region=region, 
           jobId="ab4f5d05-e890-4ff5-96ef-017df2b5c0bc").execute()
```

But , what if I dont know the job_id, and want to know the status of all the Jobs

Answer (score 0):

To list jobs in a cluster, you can use the `list()` method:

```
clusterName = 'cluster-1'
res = dpclient.dataproc.projects().regions().jobs().list(
       projectId=project, 
       region=region, 
       clusterName=clusterName).execute()
```

However, note that this only currently supports listing by clusters which still exist; even though you pass in a `clusterName`, this is resolved to a unique `cluster_uuid` under the hood; this also means if you create multiple clusters of the same name, each incarnation is still considered a different cluster, so job listing is only performed on the currently running version of the clusterName. This is by design, since `clusterName` is often reused by people for different purposes (especially if using the default generated names created in cloud.google.com/console), and logically the jobs submitted to different actual cluster instances may not be related to each other.

In the future there will be more filter options for job listings.